# How to use third party notification area with gnome shell

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell

I'm using gnome-shell 3.0.2 on Arch Linux and I want to use [AWN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avant_Window_Navigator)'s notification area plugin. However when I try to activate the plugin it complains that there's already a notification area running.

This is expected, of course, except that I can't find a way to disable gnome-shell's notification area. In gnome 2 I'd just right click on the notification area and select "remove from panel" - how do I do the equivalent in gnome-shell, so I can use awn's notification area (or any other third party notification area)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, you cannot.  It is core functionality in the current GNOME shell.

Comment: How disappointing :-(